# define variable inside vs outside in Java?

Tags: java, iteration, micro-optimization

Suppose we have a double loop with a large number of iteration, should we define the variable outside the loop for speed up? Just for example:

```
for(int i=0;i<2000;i++)
     for(int j=0;j<1000;j++)
          System.out.println(i+j);
```

Since we initialize j each time when i changes the value, is it better to declare j outside, such as:

```
 for(int i=0;i<2000;i++){
     int j=0;
     for(j=0;j<1000;j++)
          System.out.println(i+j); 
  }
```

For myself, I like the first way, it is more readable. However, I am not sure does the second way will speed up the program or not?

Comment: `j` will be initialized the same number of times either way.

Comment: Due to the lack of brackets the second program and the first program do entirely different things btw...  And the second form won't compile anyways

Comment: The second way is not an optimisation - it is the opposite, a pessimisation, because it assigns to the variable _twice_ the number of times as the first way (assuming you insert the necessary curly brackets to fix the problem identified by @fvu).

Comment: You probably meant to define j outside both loops, but still there would be no point. You could find this out yourself by timing both versions. My guess is the difference would be negligible.

Comment: No need for timing - see my answer below: the generated bytecode is identical

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add the brakets for the second method.

Answer (score 1):

No, the second form is not better in any way (it won't even compile because you missed the init-section of the for-loop)!

The for statement is built as follows: `for (init, expression, update) statement`

- The `init` statement will be executed just ONCE before the loop
  starts
- The `expression` statement will be executed before every iteration of
  the loop. Only if it results to `true`, the loop will continue.
- The `update` statement will be executed right after every iteration.
- The `statement` is the statement that will be executed in every
  iteration.

So it's just a short form of:

```
init;
while (expression) {
    statement;
    update;
}
```

As `init` will only be executed once, it's no optimization if you put it before the `for` loop.

Answer (score 1):

The code generated by Javac is exactly the same, so there cannot be any difference:

Given a "Test.java"  file:

```
public class Test {

    public static int a(int[][] v) {
        int sum = 0;
        int rows = v.length;
        int cols = v[0].length; // yes, this fails if v[0] is null
        for (int j=0; j<rows; j++) {
            for (int i=0; i<cols; i++) {
                sum += v[j][i];
            }           
        }
        return sum;
    }

    public static int b(int[][] v) {
        int sum = 0;
        int rows = v.length;
        int cols = v[0].length; // yes, this fails if v[0] is null
        int j, i;
        for (j=0; j<rows; j++) {
            for (i=0; i<cols; i++) {
                sum += v[j][i];
            }           
        }
        return sum;
    }
}
```

Compile (`javac Test.java`) and look at the bytecode (result of `javap -c Test`) in the class-file. Here is `b`:

```
public static int b(int[][]);
  Code:
   0:   iconst_0
   1:   istore_1
   2:   aload_0
   3:   arraylength
   4:   istore_2
   5:   aload_0
   6:   iconst_0
   7:   aaload
   8:   arraylength
   9:   istore_3
   10:  iconst_0
   11:  istore  4
   13:  iload   4
   15:  iload_2
   16:  if_icmpge   50
   19:  iconst_0
   20:  istore  5
   22:  iload   5
   24:  iload_3
   25:  if_icmpge   44
   28:  iload_1
   29:  aload_0
   30:  iload   4
   32:  aaload
   33:  iload   5
   35:  iaload
   36:  iadd
   37:  istore_1
   38:  iinc    5, 1
   41:  goto    22
   44:  iinc    4, 1
   47:  goto    13
   50:  iload_1
   51:  ireturn
```

You get *exactly* the same byte-code for both `a` and `b`

Answer (score 0):

There is no point in doing so. Builtin types have no remarkable setup cost.

The thing is different with objects.

You should predeclare Objects outside the loop for performance reasons. I tested this with JDK 1.4, never again since then. Possibly newer JDKs will optimize this away.

```
for(int i=0;i<2000;i++)
   for(int j=0;j<1000;j++)
      String x = "Hello " + j;
```

is remarkably slower than (define outside loop)

```
String x;
for(int i=0;i<2000;i++)
   for(int j=0;j<1000;j++)
      x = "Hello " + j;
```

is remarkably slower than (final in loop)

```
for(int i=0;i<2000;i++)
   for(int j=0;j<1000;j++)
       final String x = "Hello " + j;
```

update: just ran a timing with JDK 7u45, 1000 x 1000 iterations

I have set the code to run the loops more than once and to keep the variables in a result array. Another run will not store the variables outside the loop.

- String allocation in loop and store in array:       Avg 109.49 / NoGC: 47-49 (*)
- String allocation in loop and no store:             Avg  43.5  / NoGC: 39-47
- String allocation outside loop and store in array:  Avg  98.9  / NoGC: 42-44
- String allocation outside loop and no store:        Avg  28.25 / NoGC: 27-32
- final String allocation in loop and store in array: Avg  98.92 / NoGC: 42-50
- final String allocation in loop and no store:       Avg  28.31 / NoGC: 27-34

The results show, that the declaration of the object takes it's toll. But the real driver is the GC. The effects of declaration inside the loop or outside are small over time, if the value is used outside the loop. Using a final String inside the loop will make no difference. 
If you do not store outside the loop, the difference is remarkable between the declaration of the variable inside the loop or outside, final, again, makes no difference.

(* When storing all the values, most of the time was lost in GC runs, that is why I added the span of the runs without GC.)

Comment: what does the "final" version do? Can you edit to show how it works?

Comment: keeping the String final made no difference when I ran the tests again multiple times. That was strange, so I decided, I need to fix setup effects of the JVM. So I rewrote the test to run the loops many times. The effects are now much more clear. The final does nothing. There is a real difference in place of declaration, if you actually use the value outside the loop or only inside. It is a pity, that the speed gain does not follow the semantics: If _not_ used outside, it is better to declare outside.